# python mechanize blank download or how to do it in casperjs

Tags: python, mechanize, casperjs

I am downloading information for a research project from a site that uses ajax to load URLs and does not allow serial downloading. I am dumping the urls from `casperjs` into a file I read and use `browser.retrieve(url,dump_filename)` to download the information with `mechanize`. I mostly get blank file downloads but they are periodically filled with content. Is there a way to modify the headers so that I can always get data. Also, a `casperjs` download alternative is welcome. I have tried `casperjs` download() but it saves a blank file as well. I think it has something to do with the headers. File downloads always work in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) over Mechanize when it comes to more "sophisticated" web-sites, that use AJAX, JS, etc.

You said downloading works, when you're using your browser. Well Selenium does the same thing - it uses Firefox on your desktop to fulfill its tasks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like selenium will work for now. I shall look for a way to load it without the overhead of actually loading a browser.